# RHEL7 package updates

Tags: google-compute-engine, rhel7

I tryed to update packages of my RHEL7 VM on Google Compute Engine with `yum distro-sync` and `yum check-update` but no packages has been updated, is this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I just check on my RHEL VM, are you running the commands as root?

I run the command with sudo in front and both commands work.

You can refer to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root) on how to run a command as administrator (root)

Comment: Can you post the command output? There are many reason for a VM not connecting to the outside. For example, have you enable any external IP address?

Comment: I can't post command output beacause I connect to the VM with SSH, but the VM is connected to the outside and have an external and an internal IP address.

Comment: Mmm...without seeing the output it would be difficult to diagnose. Are you able to open a ticket with Google? https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Comment: `yum distro-sync` give `No packages marked for distribution synchronization` as output while `yum check-update` give `Security: kernel-3.10.0.1127.18.2.el7.x86_64 is an installed security update` and `Security: kernel-3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 is the currently running version` as output.

Comment: Hi there is a similar case on stack exchange and it happens for CentOS7. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459192/centos-7-no-packages-marked-for-update 
Apparently they fix it by running "yum clean all"
Give it a try and let me know